# Facebook development toolkit for .net - setinfo

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook

I'm playing with the Facebook development toolkit and I can't get profile.setinfo to work.  The documentation is not useful.  I'm using the latest source - 28656.

Can someone post a VB.Net example for me please?

Update:  I was asked for a specific problem, so here it is:

Setinfo takes a List(Of facebook.Schema.info_field)

and info_field is supposed to take a List (Of facebook.Schema.info_item)

but it seems to want an itemsLocalType instead.  So the error is

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[facebook.Schema.info_item]' to type 'itemsLocalType'.

Comment: You can find samples by Googling... if you have a specific problem post the details.

Comment: Maybe you can, but I can't - at least not one that works.  If you do have one, please post the link.

Comment: Now that I've posted the answer all over the web, you should be able to find it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally worked it out on my own:

```
Dim items = New facebook.Schema.info_field.itemsLocalType     
items.info_item.add(New Schema.info_item With {.label = "Happy", .image = "http://imageurl1/", .sublabel = "", .description = "The original and still undefeated.", .link = "http://www.scottstonehouse.ca/blog"})

items.info_item.Add(New Schema.info_item With {.label = "Indifferent", .image = "http://imageurl2/", .sublabel = "", .description = "meh....", .link = "http://www.scottstonehouse.ca/blog"})

items.info_item.Add(New Schema.info_item With {.label = "Sad", .image = "http://imageurl3/", .sublabel = "", .description = "Oh my god! you killed my dog!", .link = "http://www.scottstonehouse.ca/blog"})

items.info_item.Add(New Schema.info_item With {.label = "Cool", .image = "http://imageurl4/", .sublabel = "", .description = "Yeah. whatever", .link = "http://www.scottstonehouse.ca/blog"})

Dim ifields = New List(Of facebook.Schema.info_field)()

ifields.Add(New facebook.Schema.info_field With {.field = "test field name", .items = items})

_fbService.API.profile.setInfo("Info Title", 5, ifields, _fbService.API.uid)
```